# How to pass a function instead of string as a prop to a component

Tags: reactjs

I'm really new to reactjs and I was looking for a simple way to change the color of a button depending on states. Basically I'm using reactstrap and I have a button, I want its color to be "secondary", "danger" or "primary" the Button tag works that way :

```
<Button color={String} />
```

I want to use a function to put a String in there. basically here is a small function :

```
buttonClassName(radioId) {
    if (this.state.whatevs.valid === false)
        return "danger";
    if (this.state.whatevs.value === radioId)
        return "primary";
    return "secondary;
}
```

here is how I want to use it :

```
<Button outline color={() => this.buttonClassName(1)}>blah blah1</Button>
<Button outline color={() => this.buttonClassName(2)}>blah blah2</Button>
<Button outline color={() => this.buttonClassName(3)}>blah blah3</Button>
```

and so on for more buttons, problem is, react logically barks at me because :

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `color` of type `function` supplied to `Button`, expected `string`.
```

I agree with it, but how can I make that string change without passing a function, do I have to make state out of it, it seems so boringly circumvoluted. When I only had two states, I could just do something like that :

```
<Button outline color={(whatevs.valid === false)?"danger":"secondary"}>blah blah1</Button>
```

and that's not really a string either, but it worked.

Comment: change `color={() => this.buttonClassName(1)}` to `color={this.buttonClassName(1)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most definetly use a function to return a string. The problem with your implementation is that you were passing a *whole function by reference* rather than the *result of a function*.

Just do this simple fix below. This will execute the function and return the desired string to the `<Button>` component.

```
<Button outline color={this.buttonClassName(1)}>blah blah1</Button>
<Button outline color={this.buttonClassName(2)}>blah blah2</Button>
<Button outline color={this.buttonClassName(3)}>blah blah3</Button>
```

Comment: I probably have a bigger problem understanding react, I was under the impression I had to use something like : "this.buttonClassName = this.buttonClassName(this)" to be able to access the state from inside the function. so as long as I had this, your solution wouldn't work, now that I commented that line, it works.